# Error while creating a SOAP document: IllegalArgumentException saying local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, xml-parsing

I have a piece of code that is trying to create a new Soap message and adding a fault document in it.

```
public static SOAPMessage getMessage() throws SOAPException {
    SOAPMessage message = newSoapMessage((XmlObject) null);
    SOAPBody respBody = message.getSOAPBody();
    respBody.addDocument(newFaultDocument("soap:Server","faultText"));
    message.saveChanges();
    return message;
}

public static Document newFaultDocument(String faultCode, String faultString) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    try {
        Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        Element fault = doc.createElementNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "Fault:abc");
        doc.appendChild(fault);

        Element faultCodeElement = doc.createElement("faultcode");
        faultCodeElement.setTextContent(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(faultCode));
        fault.appendChild(faultCodeElement);

        Element faultStringElement = doc.createElement("faultstring");
        faultStringElement.setTextContent(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(faultString));
        fault.appendChild(faultStringElement);

        return doc;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected exception while creating Fault document", e);
    }
}

public static <T extends XmlObject> SOAPMessage newSoapMessage(T soapBody) {
    try {
        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
        SOAPBody respBody = message.getSOAPBody();

        if (soapBody != null) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            respBody.addDocument(factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(soapBody.newInputStream()));
            message.saveChanges();
        }

        return message;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected exception while creating SOAP message", e);
    }
}
```

I am calling the getMessage() function to get the document but it fails with the following stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: local part cannot be "null" when creating a QName
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:244)
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.<init>(ElementImpl.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementFactory.createElement(ElementFactory.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.registerChildNodes(SOAPDocumentImpl.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.registerChildNodes(SOAPDocumentImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.registerChildNodes(SOAPDocumentImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.importNode(SOAPDocumentImpl.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.BodyImpl.addDocument(BodyImpl.java:259)
    at com.example.demo.Demo1Application.getMessage(Demo1Application.java:29)
    at com.example.demo.Demo1Application.main(Demo1Application.java:23)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried figuring out how the local part is to be set in QName but couldn't figure out where and how it is to be done. Any help will be highly appreciated.